# реализация IP телефонии на RTP протоколе

Tags: rtp

Здравствуйте, стоит вопрос реализовать IP телефонию на RTP8711AM. Не могли бы посоветовать материал и либы для этого. У меня будет модуль через Wi-Fi связываться с роутером и через него устанавливать связь с телефоном. Мне нужен RTP сервер на RTL и RTP клиент на андройд. Не могли бы дать готовые примеры реализации? или подсказать, что и как, как это делается?

Comment: Sip и так есть на rtp

Comment: да, но какие использовать либы?...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html

Comment: Так это же для Андройд. Мне надо для Cortex. Или оно там тоже будет работать? Просто я думал, что Sip и RTP это разные протоколы, которые выполняют примерно одну задачу.

Comment: ты и написал, что нужно на андроид

Comment: Ой, да, просто мне надо на android и на Cortex)))

Comment: проблема в чем?

Comment: ну это же либы для андройд... Я просто не совсем понимаю разницу между sip и rtp. Какие мне библиотеки использовать, что бы поднять сервер с ip-телефонией на RTL8711AM (там стоит Cortex M3).. ?

Comment: в вопросе измени модель

Comment: Написано, то в нем и так есть RTP сервер https://esp8266.ru/forum/threads/sip-server-na-esp8266-kak-realizovat.2343/page-2#post-34455

Comment: Я знаю) но как им пользоваться?)) как его запустить?)) какие библиотеки?